# Control timing of email arrival

Tags: gmail, email-filter

Richard Stallman downloads email once a day: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RichardStallman

How can I replicate this in Gmail? Specifically, I'd like something that would deliver all of the messages I received throughout the day at noon (so that I could not read them before then). Of course I could just *not* check Gmail more than once a day, but I am not tough enough to do that (yet).

Right now I am using a Python script + cron job to deliver messages to a second address, where the messages appear at the specified time. Is there a way to let me read the messages in the original account? I was thinking you could use clever filters in Gmail to forward everything to a holding account, and then append some key to the message, but is there a better way?

Comment: Stallman also uses `wget` as a web browser, so you might want to consider doing that as well.  Also, I think that you will find meditation helpful.

Comment: paradroid - Thanks, it's not so much about being paranoid or pro-free software as it is about being able to focus on more productive things than checking my email.

Comment: That is why I suggested meditation.  Mindfulness helps you control your thoughts, by being aware of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a program called fetchmail which pulls email down via POP or IMAP and then sends that email to a location of your choosing.  fetchmail works with gmail.  You could run it once a day.